# What was Persephone Hazard doing at the time of "The Nightmare Stacks"

Tags: charles-stross, laundry-files

In The Laundry Files book 7: "The Nightmare Stacks",
CASE NIGHTMARE RED occurs.

I am trying to recall what Persephone Hazard doing during that time.
She occurs in previous and subsequent books, and I feel like she was at least mentioned in book 7, but can not recall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Persephone Hazard was very briefly mentioned in Chapter 12 of 'The Nightmare Stacks' but played no other role in the story.

Excerpt from Chapter 12 (**bold** emphasis by me)...

> this is understood by all present. Johnny doesn’t answer to anyone except **Persephone**.

One page further in the same chapter:-

> Seems to me you don’t want to get ’**Seph** out of bed for this. She’s still jet-lagged from that caper in Queensland last Thursday.”
>   Vikram shakes his head. “Then we shall let BASHFUL INCENDIARY sleep in,” he agrees. Sending one of the Laundry’s most powerful witches on a wild goose chase is a bad idea: **Persephone** has a vicious temper when sleep-deprived.